# ADT error: Could not create the view: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.views.tasks

Tags: eclipse, adt, tasklist

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I am not able to view Task List, and the Task List window has the error as written above/below.

```
Could not create the view: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.views.tasks
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case to solve it I just went to [Eclipse Marketplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pEOY.png), searched for Mylyn and [installed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vtg9.png). Afterwards the eclipse restarted and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the error message "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.views.tasks" is concerned, here's what happened in my case and how I solved it:

I had this problem with Eclipse Neon version (not Luna/Mars), i.e. the error message appeared in the 'Task List' view each time I started Eclipse, even if I used  "-no-activate-task" in the command line.

The problem was most probably because I was using a "customized" environment created with previous versions and let Neon adapt it the first time I run it.

After I created a new "customized" environment from scratch, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In Mars, I had the same problem after trying to install the TaskDev Jira connector, which didn't work.  Ultimately, I had to delete all the org.eclipse.mylyn.* references in the features and plugins directory and grabbed them from the original Mars download.